# WebView not reflecting changes to web page contents

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a web application running on an AWS and an Android app which is just a WebView to just reflect the web application.

I had the **setAppCacheEnabled** set to **True** earlier, but I commented that piece of code in the recent version of the application.

Anytime an update is made to the web page contents, the change does not reflect on the Android WebView.

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //improve  webView performance
        myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        //myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(<my web application URL>);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear the data of the application or uninstall it once?

Comment: That is not the solution to the issue. The user of the application won't be aware of any changes to the webpage being reflected in the webview.